# Is it legal to make a non-military stealth plane?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations, military, stealth, regulations

Just as military camouflage can be legally worn by civilians on most jurisdictions (e.g., in the U.S.), can I create a stealth aircraft for non-military use? More precisely, can I register and fly the thing?

Comment: In which country? Keep in mind that USA & the rest of the world are different planets in terms of weapon laws. What is legal in the USA could get you 10 years in prison in an EU country only for possessing it.

Comment: Making a plane "look stealthy" and making it actually stealthy are two very different things.

Comment: See also [The Facetmobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wainfan_Facetmobile)

Comment: Just theory, but you may find some of the materials you need hard to get, simply because their only purpose is military use.  In fact, I would expect the vast majority of the surface treatments used are not just hard to get, but actually classified.

Comment: I don't know about FAA certification, but I'd bet the DEA would be mighty interested in what you were doing!

Comment: Usually people doing "stealthy" stuff are not interested in "registration".

Comment: Why would it be illegal? Is there a specific law that specifies the RF reflectivity of an aircraft?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you may, but you need to carry a [mode C transponder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_transponder_interrogation_modes#Mode_A_and_Mode_C) while above 10,000 ft or in some types of [controlled airspace](http://www.aopa.org/Pilot-Resources/PIC-archive/Equipment/Transponder-Requirements) and have it switched on. Which pretty much negates the stealth capabilities of your aircraft.

To quote the linked AOPA page:

> According to 14 CFR 99.13, no person may operate an aircraft into or
>   out of the United States, or into, within, or across an ADIZ
>   designated in subpart B unless operating a transponder with Mode C.
>   Certain exemptions might apply to aircraft that were not originally
>   certified with an engine-driven electrical system; see 99.13(d).

Comment: Any examples of what aircraft have been covered under the exemptions they talk about?

Comment: "Which pretty much negates the stealth capabilities of your aircraft." Well let's just say most of it is just for show. Like driving a sports car on speed-limited roadways. :-)

Comment: @curious_cat 99.13(d) covers "...an aircraft which was not originally certificated with an engine-driven electrical system and which has not subsequently been certified with such a system installed, a balloon, or a glider." - https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/99.13 It makes sense that you get an exception if you aren't certified to have a power supply to run the transponder!

Comment: @Andrew The phrasing made me wonder whether there is such a beast as an "aircraft certified with a **non-engine-driven electrical system"** Would such a craft be able to run a transponder off whatever drives their power supply? Batteries? Fuel Cells?

Comment: @Andrew Also, as an pedantic aside, would one of the recent solar powered craft be excluded technically from the "engine-driven" definition & hence be able to find a loophole for not operating a transponder? Though God only knows why someone would want to do that. But just a hypothetical question.

Comment: @curious_cat no idea - but note there's nothing in there saying you can't carry a transponder if exempt, just that you don't have to!

Comment: Put another way, I don't think there is any country in the world where flying a stealth aircraft under stealth would not be considered either a de-jure or de-facto act of aggression.  A "non-military" use of a stealth aircraft, therefore, simply does not exist.

Comment: @markgarcia - you could just make a plane that looked stealthy but wasn't particularly, if it was just for show...

Comment: @curious_cat: plenty of battery electrical systems. Think Piper J-3 Cub. No alternator or electric when built, but you can always run a radio or night lighting from a battery.

Comment: The Mode C transponder alone doesn't do it. ATC would require you to show up on their radar, with complete position given.

Comment: @jjack: But this is what a transponder is for. A stealthy airframe will not create the primary echo but still transmit the squawk, so it is visible to the ground controller. Of course, this requires a ground radar which displays a squawk even if it cannot be matched to a primary echo.

Comment: The Mode C transponder just gives altitude, according to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Lat and Long are figured out by the rader station from the timing of the transponder reply.

Comment: @Andrew: Great, now I'm trying to imagine a stealth glider...